# Date of birth restriction

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to restrict my date picker dialog to select a minimum of 18 years of age

```
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val abc = findViewById<Button>(R.id.birth)


    abc.setOnClickListener {
        DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear, mMonth, mDay ->
            date.setText("" + mDay +"/" + mMonth +"/" + mYear)
        }, year, month, day).show()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it this way

```
val calendarMaxDate = Calendar.getInstance()
calendarMaxDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18)

val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear, mMonth, mDay ->
                        date.setText("" + mDay +"/" + mMonth +"/" + mYear)
                    }, year, month, day)
    datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendarMaxDate.timeInMillis
    datePickerDialog.show()
```

Comment: it is working but when I select february as the month it shows the number of the as 1 not 2 e.g 12/1/1998 where it should be 12/2/1998

Comment: That's because [the months in Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#MONTH) as well as in [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener#onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int)) (see the month field description on this link) class are indexed 0 - 11 and not 1 - 12. So 0 is January, 1 is February, and so on. It will return -1 for every month you select, e.g. if you selected the date 12 May 1998, it will be returned as 12/4/1998 not as 12/5/1998 as you might have expected it to.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the actual number of the month

Comment: Add one (+1) the month value you get. You should read and practice more about Calendar and DatePicker.

Comment: Its not working it doesn't add 1 to the month it shows the next month

Comment: It doesn't show the next month. Please read the docs at the links I mentioned above in comments.

Comment: c.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1) I wrote this it goes  to the next month and still shows the wrong number

Answer (score 0):

use below

```
  val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR,-18)
```