# Recycler View Item flip

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Actually I am using recycler view and adding a layout in the rows and I am using flip animation on cardviews(when clicked on it). The problem is when I add multiple items in the recycler the flip animation works only with the first item. I used toast to make sure that click function is working with other items or not, turns out it's working but flip animation is not working with any other items.Can any one help me out here

This is my code

```
override fun onCardClick(item: PacketModel, position: Int) {


        val scale = this.resources.displayMetrics.density
        frontCard.cameraDistance= 8000 * scale
        backCard.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale




        front_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.front_animator) as AnimatorSet
        back_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.back_animator) as AnimatorSet

        if (isFront){
            front_anim.setTarget(frontCard)
            back_anim.setTarget(backCard)
            front_anim.start()
            back_anim.start()
            isFront = false

        }else
        {
            front_anim.setTarget(backCard)
            back_anim.setTarget(frontCard)
            back_anim.start()
            front_anim.start()
            isFront = true


        }


        Toast.makeText(context, item.Name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

This is the adapter Class

```
class PacketAdapter (val packetList: ArrayList<PacketModel> , var clickListener2: onPacketItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<PacketAdapter.ViewHolder>(){



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val a = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.packet, parent, false)


        return ViewHolder(a)


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {


        return packetList.size

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val packet : PacketModel = packetList[position]



        holder.intialize(packet, clickListener2)


    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {

        val packetTime = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.packetTime)
        val timeMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeMessage)


        fun intialize(item: PacketModel, action: onPacketItemClickListener){

            packetTime.text = item.Name
            timeMessage.text = item.Age

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                action.onCardClick(item, adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

    interface onPacketItemClickListener{
        fun onCardClick (item: PacketModel, position: Int)

    }

}
```

Comment: there is a library for card flip you can use that library .. https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your card flipping code inside your recyclerview adapter so that recyclerview can recycle it as it should be. You can place your card flipping code inside itemview onClicklistener:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener {

     // Place your flipping code here

     action.onCardClick(item, adapterPosition)
 }
```

Remove flipping code from onCardClick callback. Let me know if it works fine.

Comment: Thank you sir..its working now
and one more thing can you tell me how to get the correct number of month from DateTimePicker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309658/date-of-birth-restriction
you can see my last comment I am using date time picker in my signup but when select some date it shows the wrong numberof month for e.g I am choosing 10th of April  1998 the date should be like this "10/4/1998" instead it shows "10/3/1998" , It always shows 1 less number in month field

Comment: You can open a new question with your code of dateTime picker that you already did so that I can identify the fault and correct it. Open a new question and mention me there by comment, I am on your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198400/date-picker-shows-wrong-month  here you go