# How to click a button inside a recyclerview item in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am putting a button inside my recycler view item, but I am not able to perform any action on clicking that button, I know how to click a recyclerview item but I don't know how to click specific element of item in recycler view

This function is used to click recycler view item
     override fun onCardClick(item: PacketModel, position: Int) {

```
        lateinit var front_anim: AnimatorSet
        lateinit var back_anim: AnimatorSet


        val scale = this.resources.displayMetrics.density
        packetRecView.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale
        packetRecView.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale





        front_anim =
            AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.front_animator) as AnimatorSet
        back_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.back_animator) as AnimatorSet

        if (isFront) {
            front_anim.setTarget(flip.cardOnFront)
            back_anim.setTarget(flip.backCard)
            front_anim.start()
            back_anim.start()
            isFront = false

        } else {
            front_anim.setTarget(flip.backCard)
            back_anim.setTarget(flip.cardOnFront)
            back_anim.start()
            front_anim.start()
            isFront = true


        }




        Toast.makeText(context, item.drugs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

This is my Adapter

```
class PacketAdapter (val packetList: ArrayList<PacketModel> , var clickListener2: onPacketItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<PacketAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val a = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.packet, parent, false)




        return ViewHolder(a)


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {


        return packetList.size

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val packet : PacketModel = packetList[position]

        holder.intialize(packet, clickListener2)


    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {

     //   val takenButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.taken)

        val fCard = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardOnFront)
        val packetTime = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeofPacket)
        val timeMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.messageofTime)
        val bCars = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.backCard)
        val drugs = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.drugs)
        val note = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.note)
        val dosage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dosage)






        fun intialize(item: PacketModel, action: onPacketItemClickListener){




//            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault())
//            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
//            val result = formatter.parse(dateAsString)
//
//
//



//            takenButton.setOnClickListener(this)


            var date = (((item.date) as Timestamp).seconds) * 1000L
            fun convertLongToTime(time: Long): String {
                val date = Date(time)
                val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")
                format.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5")

                return format.format(date)
            }
            var convertedDate = convertLongToTime(date)
            packetTime.text = convertedDate
            timeMessage.text = ""
            drugs.text = item.drugs
            note.text  = item.notes
            dosage.text = item.dosage

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                action.onCardClick(item, adapterPosition)
            }



        }
    }




    interface onPacketItemClickListener{
        fun onCardClick (item: PacketModel, position: Int)
    }


}
```

Now I want to perform click action inside the recyclerview item. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code suppose your desired button is `myButton` and you define it to your adapter like:

```
    val myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.myButton) // This is your Button, you declared in your xml file.
    val fCard = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardOnFront)
    val packetTime = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeofPacket)
    val timeMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.messageofTime)
    val bCars = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.backCard)
    val drugs = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.drugs)
    val note = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.note)
    val dosage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dosage)
```

Then just simply call `myButton.setOnClickListener` inside your `initialize` function in your adapter like:

```
    fun intialize(item: PacketModel, action: onPacketItemClickListener) {
        var date = (((item.date) as Timestamp).seconds) * 1000L
        fun convertLongToTime(time: Long): String {
            val date = Date(time)
            val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")
            format.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5")

            return format.format(date)
        }
        var convertedDate = convertLongToTime(date)
        packetTime.text = convertedDate
        timeMessage.text = ""
        drugs.text = item.drugs
        note.text  = item.notes
        dosage.text = item.dosage

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            action.onCardClick(item, adapterPosition)
        }

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Do whatever you want on your button click as like you did to your recycler-view item click 
            //action.onCardClick(item, adapterPosition)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Tameem If my solution is right and worked for you then please accept it as the right answer of your question

Comment: yes this is the correct answer and can you please take a look at this one also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017338/recycler-view-item-flip

Comment: Any idea, how to prevent clicking on two buttons at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

i have created interface between activity and adapter that send item where was user has click, in especicify one button inside. my code:

```
//create file:  New-> Kotlin class->Interface, you are going to write:
 
interface CellClickListener {
    fun onCellClickListener(data: Entregas)
}


//in your adapter received this interface in parameters of class

class EntregasAdapter(val context: Context, val entregas:List<Entregas>,
                      val cellClickListener: CellClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<EntregasAdapter.EntregasViewHolder>(), {


 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EntregasViewHolder, position: Int) {
     val entregas : Entregas= entregasFilterList[position]

      holder.my_button.setOnClickListener {
              cellClickListener.onCellClickListener(entregas)
           }
 }

  inner class EntregasViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
     var my_button=itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.my_button)

}

}


//in MainActivity, you should used interface

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),CellClickListener  {

lateinit var  adapter: EntregasAdapter


   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

 adapter= EntregasAdapter(this@MainActivity,List<Entregas>,this@MainActivity)
                   

                    val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
                     recyclerview.adapter=adapter
                    recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
}

   override fun onCellClickListener(data: Entregas) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cell clicked:"+data.nombre_cliente, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```